# How to construct a threshold map with maximum average distance between consecutive values?

Tags: algorithm, distance, point

I have a pre-generated 2D point cloud like :
[image]

Let's state the grid contains 64 points.
To each point, I would like to assign a value in the range [0,63] such that:

- there is no points with a value already assigned (easy)
- for a given point with a given value, the average distance between successive numbers is as large as possible AND ensuring that the table "wraps" around at edges

Basically it is the same algorithm that is applied to the [Bayer Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering), except that my points are not in an axis aligned grid.

> Arbitrary size threshold maps can be devised with a simple rule: First fill each slot with a successive integers. Then reorder them such that the average distance between two successive numbers in the map is as large as possible, ensuring that the table "wraps" around at edges.

I tried to search for algorithm to generate non power of two matrix but I didn't find any relevant algorithm.

How can I achieve to satisfy the second conditions ?

**EDIT 1:**

Point count in the cloud is not a power of two !

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the result, as you can see some range seems to be axis aligned distributed and it is not really valid for me if I want to only use some ranges.

I will try to find a way to add some jitter.
Do you have any tips to achieve that ?

Range [0,0.1]
[[image: enter image description here]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL6Xs.png)

Range [0.1,0.2]
[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfpYd.png)

Range [0.8, 0.9]
[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGHlh.png)

Range [0, 1]
[[image]][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ySK4.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you want to google "blue noise mask"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given 4^k points not in a grid, you can assign them to points in a 2^k by 2^k grid and then label each point by the associated value in the Bayer Matrix. The assignment process resembles the construction of a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). You partition the set of points into equal-sized subsets where one subset is entirely to the left of the other. The x coordinates of the points in the left subset begin with 0 in binary notation; the x coordinates of the points in the right subset begin with 1. Then you recursively subdivide each subset by y coordinate, determining the first bit of the y coordinates in the grid. Then make a recursive call on the subsubsets to find the rest of the bits.

Python code:

```
import operator


def threshold_map_recursive(points, base, increment, result):
    if len(points) == 0:
        return
    if len(points) == 1:
        result[points[0]] = base
        return
    n3, r = divmod(len(points), 4)
    n0 = n3 + (r > 0)
    n2 = n3 + (r > 2)
    points.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    left = points[: n0 + n3]
    left.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    threshold_map_recursive(left[:n0], base, 4 * increment, result)
    threshold_map_recursive(left[n0:], base + 3 * increment, 4 * increment, result)
    right = points[n0 + n3 :]
    right.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    threshold_map_recursive(right[:n2], base + 2 * increment, 4 * increment, result)
    threshold_map_recursive(right[n2:], base + increment, 4 * increment, result)


def threshold_map(points):
    result = {}
    threshold_map_recursive(list(points), 0, 1, result)
    return result


def test(n, m):
    tm = threshold_map((x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(m))
    for k in range(1, n * m):
        for y in range(m):
            print("".join("@" if tm[x, y] < k else "." for x in range(n)))
        print()


test(5, 5)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Currently I have no guarantee that my point cloud contains a power of two points, so mapping values to a power of two grid then map it to the bayer matrix won't be accurate I guess.

Isn't there any other way ?

Comment: As long as the density is uniform, there's an adjustment that can be made. I'll try to post code in the next day or so.

Comment: @Qzaac Added some Python. The results aren't perfect, but they're pretty good.

Comment: @DavidEistenstat sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot for the code !!!
I have tried your algorithm and it seems to works well.
After some experiences it seems it properly recreate the bayer matrix for axis aligned power of two point cloud but not for non power of two (I carefully translated your code in c++ so it seems to come from the algorithm).
Also it seems some range of values seem to be axis aligned, and I have to fixe it.
I will edit my post to show you the result